# Understanding reusable code in multiple dynamically created buttons in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My application has multiple, dynamically created pages with a dynamically created button list in each page header. Thus I am trying to use reusable code.

I have read these related articles ([Exploring Reusability with D3.js](https://bocoup.com/weblog/reusability-with-d3/) and [Towards Reusable Charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)) and searched d3.js 'cloning' as well as stackoverflow posts.

My solution so far appears to be flexible and useful to me. Example:

```
d3.select("#select-viewer").append("div")
  .attr("id","btn-group-select-view").call(function(d,i) {

    for (var i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
        d3.select("#btn-group-select-view")
          .append("button")
          .attr("type","button")
          .attr("class","btn-btn")
          .attr("id",function(d) { return 'button '+i;})
          .append("div")
          .attr("class","label")
          .text(function(d) { return 'button '+i;})
    }

    for (var i = 16; i < 30; i++) {
        d3.select("#btn-group-select-view2")
          .append("button")
          .attr("type","button")
          .attr("class","btn-btn")
          .attr("id",function(d) { return 'button '+i;})
          .append("div")
          .attr("class","label")
          .text(function(d) { return 'button '+i;})
    }
});
```

Would it be an improvement to create this function:

```
function button(selection,classname,id,text) {
  selection
          .append("button")
          .attr("type","button")
          .attr("class",classname)
          .attr("id",id)
          .append("div")
          .attr("class","label")
          .text(text)
}
```

and append it to an element?

```
 d3.selectAll("div").call(button(classname,id,text));
```

Or (not sure about the code's syntax here yet):

```
 d3.select("div") .call(function(d,i){
    for (var i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
      button(classname,id,text)
 }
});
```

I would like your feedback before I apply this on a larger scale.

Comment: I would use the usual D3 data binding pattern instead of the loop, i.e. have data representing the buttons.

Comment: If you find a moment Lars - why would you prefer that ? Thank you.

Comment: Because it uses the D3 way of doing things, which is the approach used in the reusable components implemented in D3.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. This was interesting to me because with the D3 way you have to define the data ( e.g. sections in a document ) and have the data create the buttons, which I find quite fascinating - and always surprising - as a concept.

Comment: Even though : I have 15000 records in a csv file; they are dynamically split into 15 separate blocks of 1000 - d3.csv -> data.splice(0,1000). My buttons are selecting those sections. That is: the data that could be  bound to button elements do not really exist yet. I know that I will need 15 buttons. Now I have to figure out how to 'translate' the splice action into code like: data_for_buttons = total data rows divided by thousand. That seems more complicated than the use of a 'for' statement, doesn't it.

Comment: Create an array of arrays and use [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: Ok, I have not met those yet - I will read about the nested topic. I appreciate your help and input. Thank you.